# How to lock a choice option in Symofny form's select field

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my form type for adding entities, I need to lock one option so that a user can change all fields but not the one locked.

Here is my code:

```
        ->add('network', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AcmeBundle:Network',
            'data' => $options['current_network'],
            'disabled' => true,
        ))
```

`$options['current_network']` sets the option in the filed to the expected value. With `'disabled' => true`, the field is also locked as expected.

However, when I submit the form, this field is not submitted and Symfony throws  the erros

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'network_id' cannot be
>   null

This is correct, `network_id` should not be `null`.

How can I make this field be locked to the value present in `$options['current_network']`, but still be submitted with the form?

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove it from the form and set it at the controller

```
    ...

    if ($form->isValid()){

       $entity->setNetwork($network); // whatever your network is

       $em->persist($entity);
       $em->flush();
    ...
    }
...
```

Comment: That solves the problem partly, but I'd still like to have the field on the form so that although the user cannot change the value of the select field, they know that an option is set anyway.

Comment: You can do that when you create the object you setted

$entity = new Entity();

$entity->setNetwork($network);

so when it will be shown it will have a network set by default

Comment: Actually, this is what I've already done and it works great now.

Answer (score 0):

to do that you need to set the network before binding the form

```
    $entity = new Entity();
    $entity->setNetwork($network);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()){
       $em->persist($entity);
       $em->flush();
    }
```

and at your form :

```
->add('network', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AcmeBundle:Network',
        'disabled' => true,
    ))
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use readonly instead of disabled. A readonly element is just not editable, but gets sent when the according form submits, a disabled element isn't editable and isn't sent on submit.

Comment: `read_only` and consequently HTML's `readonly` does not apply to SELECT fields. So if you set `read_only` to `true` in SF, you will still be able to select options.

Comment: So I think the only solution is to see how to emulate the readonly it's not related to SF.